# Adding a crust to sous vide pork

Tags: baking, sous-vide

I had considerable success at Christmas dinner coating a sous vide joint of beef with whipped egg white, rolling in ground yellow mustard seed, salt and pepper and baking in a really hot (240c) oven for 15 minutes or so until it baked hard.

Will the same procedure work on pork with ground sesame seeds, fennel and salt? I'm concerned that the sesame seeds or fennel will turn out bitter.

Comment: You could do a test by just baking them, possibly on a bed of whipped egg whites, and see if they’re okay at that time and temperature.